# Recursion in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am writing a selection sort, and I get it to work when I just pass in an array, but when I try to use recursion, it gives me a stack too deep error. What am I doing wrong with this?

```
def selectionSortRecursive(array, arrayPosition)
   if arrayPosition == (array.length-1)
      puts "End of the line folks!"
      return array
   end   
   while arrayPosition >= 1 && array[arrayPosition] < array[arrayPosition - 1] do 
    puts "This is pass #{arrayPosition}"
    if array[arrayPosition] < array[arrayPosition - 1]
      tmp = array[arrayPosition]
      array[arrayPosition] = array[arrayPosition - 1]
      array[arrayPosition - 1] = tmp
    end # end if
    arrayPosition += 1
  end
  selectionSortRecursive(array, arrayPosition)
  return array
end
```

This is what I am using to test it:

```
selectionSortRecursive(array, 1)
```

Comment: There is no recursive call, i.e. the function never calls itself?

Comment: Where's the recursion?  There's no call to selectionSortRecursive within the method.

Comment: If I run with `selectionSortRecursive([4,3,2,1], 1)` I get `undefined method '<' for nil:NilClass`. You need to add `&& arrayPosition <= array.length - 1` in the while condition.

Comment: Oops, during the copy and paste of my code and then forgetting that it needs 4 spaces to show up as code I lost the recursive call. I have edited this as it shows in my program. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such situations, just put print statements to see which code is executed and with which values. You would have seen :

```
$ ruby -w t4.rb 
t4.rb:21: warning: mismatched indentations at 'end' with 'while' at 10
initial array=[4, 3, 2, 1], initial position=2
last_pos=3
This is pass 2 cur=2  pre=3
after switching elements : [4, 2, 3, 1]
This is pass 3 cur=1  pre=3
after switching elements : [4, 2, 1, 3]
initial array=[4, 2, 1, 3], initial position=4
last_pos=3
initial array=[4, 2, 1, 3], initial position=4
last_pos=3
initial array=[4, 2, 1, 3], initial position=4
last_pos=3
initial array=[4, 2, 1, 3], initial position=4
last_pos=3
.......
t4.rb:2: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

To stop a recursion, you need to check some condition. Look at the millions of factorial or fibonacci examples which are always used to explain the recursion.

I'm not sure to understand how you want to sort, but this code works :

```
def selectionSortRecursive(array, arrayPosition)
   puts "initial array=#{array}, initial position=#{arrayPosition}"
   initial_array_position = arrayPosition
   last_pos = array.length - 1
   puts "last_pos=#{last_pos}"
   if arrayPosition == (last_pos)
      puts "End of the line folks!"
      return array
   end   
   while arrayPosition >= 1 && arrayPosition <= last_pos && array[arrayPosition] < array[arrayPosition - 1] do
    cur = array[arrayPosition]
    pre = array[arrayPosition - 1]
    puts "This is pass #{arrayPosition} cur=#{cur}  pre=#{pre}"
    if array[arrayPosition] < array[arrayPosition - 1]
      tmp = array[arrayPosition]
      array[arrayPosition] = array[arrayPosition - 1]
      array[arrayPosition - 1] = tmp
      puts "after switching elements : #{array}"
    end # end if
    arrayPosition += 1
   end
   selectionSortRecursive(array, arrayPosition) if arrayPosition != initial_array_position
   return array
end

p selectionSortRecursive([4,3,2,1], 2)
```

Execution :

```
$ ruby -w t4.rb 
initial array=[4, 3, 2, 1], initial position=2
last_pos=3
This is pass 2 cur=2  pre=3
after switching elements : [4, 2, 3, 1]
This is pass 3 cur=1  pre=3
after switching elements : [4, 2, 1, 3]
initial array=[4, 2, 1, 3], initial position=4
last_pos=3
[4, 2, 1, 3]
```